# Terraform - Error: no matching Route53Zone found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, cloudposse

I using `https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate` to generate certificate using terraform and aws.

I want to run this module on serval domains: "example.com", "cdn.example.com"...

I don't want to use  `subject_alternative_names` for `cdn.example.com` because it will be appear on the `subject` field inside the certificate, and when everyone open the certificate I don't want to him to see cdn domain.

For cdn.example.com I want a new certificate.

So I try to run `terraform apply` with my code below but I getting errors:

> Error: no matching Route53Zone found
>
> on .terraform\modules\acm_request_certificate_example\main.tf line 19, in
> data "aws_route53_zone" "default":   19: data "aws_route53_zone"
> "default" {
>
> Error: no matching Route53Zone found
>
> on .terraform\modules\acm_request_certificate_cdn_example\main.tf line 19, in
> data "aws_route53_zone" "default":   19: data "aws_route53_zone"
> "default" {

I can't run more than more module? How to solve it anyway?

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.12.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.12.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}
module "acm_request_certificate_example" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = "example.com"
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
}

module "acm_request_certificate_cdn_example" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = "cdn.example.com"
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
}
```

I only have `example.com` in the hosted zone.

Comment: Do you have corresponding hosted zones in route53 for these domains?

Comment: The error is because terrafom can't find hosted zone titled `otherexample.com` (or what ever you are passing). Can you go to your Route53 and check the name of the hosted zone?

Comment: I edit my question. see the different now please.

Comment: You can try with `process_domain_validation_options = false`, but then you have to manually validate the domains for the SSL cert to be issued.

Comment: Yes this is works. but as you say I have to manually validate the domains for the SSL cert to be issued. if you have any idea how to make it works anyway without me setting `process_domain_validation_options`, it will help a lot. thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer based on our discussion.

Comment: Yes Sure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using `process_domain_validation_options = true`. This checks if the **hosted zone exists** in Roure53 prior requesting a certificate. This is done to enable **automated validation** of the SSL certificate to be issued.

Since in the OP's case SSL certificates are requested for domains without corresponding zones, the terraform was erroring out.

The solution was to use `process_domain_validation_options = false`, but this requires **manual validation** procedure for the SSL to be issued. To automation of this procedure must be done through a custom solution. In very broad terms, such solution could involve created required record for the validation using [aws_route53_record](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record), a lambda function or [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) provisioner to  created needed records.